# Firefox redirects localhost to IP

Tags: firefox, routing

In chrome or Safari if I type `localhost:8573` I get sent to that address like I want. In Firefox however when I type that, I am getting rerouted to whatever my current ip address is.

Why is this behavior happening on Firefox, and how can I stop it so that I can start using Firefox for development?

Comment: What do you meant by "that address like I want"?

Comment: If I enter localhost:8573 I get sent to localhost:8573, not 10.187.42.19:8573 (or some other random ip)

Comment: It should not be the default behavior of Firefox - did you install any unwanted add-ons?